# Откуда берется undefined

Tags: javascript

Почему выводится `undefined`?

```js
var arr = ["Nick", "Jon"];
var q = prompt("Player Type", "");

function chek(arr, question) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === question) {
      alert("Such a player there");
    }
  }
};

var f = chek(arr, q);
alert(f);
```

Comment: видимо, потому, что эта функция ничего не возвращает, а лишь выводит алерт.

Answer (score 2):

потому что ваша функция возвращает дефолтное значение которое в js это `undefined` если явно с помощью инструкции `return` ничего не возвращать, тоесть `undefined` здесь алертнется в любом случае.
Просто уберите `alert(f)` и `var f =`.